# Animated spinner spins at same speed in IE after hiding/showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a css animated spinner. It uses animation to spin. There's a border on an element, its :before and its :after. Each border spins at a different speed. It works great on first page load, but in IE if it's hidden and then shown again, it all spins at the same pace.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates the problem: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9comfnob/)

Here's my css:

```
.loader-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.loader-wrapper .loader {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2372b9;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
.loader-wrapper .loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f47b27;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  -moz-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
.loader-wrapper .loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #6ba543;
  -moz-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
```

My html:

```
<div class="loader-wrapper">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0);">Hide/show</a>
```

And my javascript:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    if($(".loader").is(":visible")) {
        $(".loader").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".loader").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly this is happening-- you've probably just found a bug in IE's interpretation of the display property, or else how it handles pseudoelements. Your best bet may be to try another approach, eg. toggling a hide class with `overflow: hidden`

`.hide {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/9comfnob/1/